# Computing Hessian diagonals efficiently with torch.func

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization

I’m looking for ways to compute the diagonal of a model’s parameter Hessian with regard to the model’s input loss efficiently, ideally with PyTorch 2.0 `torch.func` and its `vmap` capabilities.
Due to memory constraints, I want to avoid computing the full Hessian and instead opt for an implementation using a Hessian vector product.

So far, I’ve been able to correctly compute the diagonal values, but the computation is incredibly slow. Any ideas how to make this computationally faster?

```py
import torch


def f(model, params, input, target):
    predictions = torch.func.functional_call(model, params, (input,))
    return torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(predictions, target)


def hvp(f, model, params, input, target, v):
    return torch.func.grad(
        lambda params: torch.dot(
            torch.cat(
                [
                    p.flatten()
                    for p in torch.func.grad(f, argnums=1)(
                        model, params, input, target
                    ).values()
                ]
            ),
            v,
        )
    )(params)


model = torch.nn.Linear(2, 2)
params = dict(model.named_parameters())

x = torch.randn(2)
y = torch.tensor(1)

num_params = sum(p.numel() for p in params.values())
hessian_diag = None
for p_i in range(num_params):
    v = torch.zeros(num_params)
    v[p_i] = 1
    hvp_dict = hvp(f, model, params, x, y, v)
    hessian_diag = (
        torch.cat(
            [
                hessian_diag,
                torch.cat([hvp_dict[param].flatten() for param in hvp_dict])[
                    p_i
                ].unsqueeze(0),
            ],
            dim=0,
        )
        if hessian_diag is not None
        else torch.cat([hvp_dict[param].flatten() for param in hvp_dict])[
            p_i
        ].unsqueeze(0)
    )
```

I tried to vectorise the computation of the dot product with no luck. That would definitely speed up the computation, however, I’m open to completely different ideas for this as well.